# share data from/to activities

Tags: android, android-activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

My situation is a bit different: I've main activity that call another one (index activities):

```
Intent index = new Intent(this, Index.class);
startActivity(index);
```

From index activity, users can choose from list.

So, I need pass index's class variables to main activities. How?

thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Activity's method `startActivityforResult`.

See an example of how it should be used over [here](http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577).

Basically the idea is to use `Bundles` to communicate data between activities. That way the activities can be restored by the system even if they were destroyed some time ago because of lack of resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, Index.class);
i.putExtra("data", "data");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in Index class use this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String data = extras.getString("data");
```

Comment: At least i understand the OP's question the other way round: the called activity needs to return result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I done:

main activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Index.class);
  startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

index: activity:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            String result = "1";
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
             returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
             setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
             finish();
```

main activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

          String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
          value=result;
     }

    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         //Write your code on no result return 

    }}
    }
```

"result" is correct variable from index activity, but I need use that variable to main class and not only in that method.

So I wish share "result" variable to entire class.

What is the way?

thanks!